# Chart.js and EJS: Display String, Not Calculation Result

Tags: date, chart.js, ejs

I am using Chart.js in an EJS template and trying to display a partial date consisting of Year/month, e.g.: 2017/02 or 2017-02, but I can't find a way to display the string rather than the calculated value, e.g.: 1008.5 or 2015.

This displays as '2017/02' in a table in EJS:

```
<%= legend %>
```

But in my chart, I get 1008.5:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [<%= labels %>],
        datasets: [{
            label: <%= legend %>,
            data: [<%= visits %>],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I've tried using <%- %>, as well as HTML entities for '/', but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to quote strings, e.g.:

```
label: '<%= legend %>',
```